# MS charts not working on server

Tags: c#, charts, windows-server-2003, asp.net-3.5

I have started using MS charts in ASP.NET 3.5 with code behind in C#

I worked with the charts which worked fine with localhost; but problem startd when i started working on the server

i get an error in web config

> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Any suggestions thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok here is how i made it work..

First i found the System.Web.DataVisualization DLL's which were present in the assemblies of MS chart control folder in my program files. i copied these to my bin folder on the local host and then published it..

then on server side i made a directory in C drive as TempDump and made the following change in web config file..

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;"  />
 </appSettings>
```

I changed this to

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempDump\;" />
</appSettings>
```

and everythig worked perfect..

thanks

Comment: I got this to work as well, but imo this is a temp situation at best

Answer (score 0):

Your ASP.Net is not configured for .Net Framework 3.5. See [Specify a .NET Framework Version for an Application Pool (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754523(WS.10).aspx)

Comment: Configuring IIS 6.0 to Use the Correct Version of the .NET Framework: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783640(WS.10).aspx

Comment: See also http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToSetAnIISApplicationOrAppPoolToUseASPNET35RatherThan20.aspx